# Hide username from menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

In Mountain Lion, my full name is displayed at the right of the menu bar (between the time and the search icon, to be specific). As it takes a lot of space, I was wondering if there is a way to hide this?

Comment: This isn't anything specific to the 10.8 release...

Comment: It's not, but when I upgraded my MBA to Mountain Lion, OS X turned on fast user switching and the corresponding menu bar extra for me.  No idea why it did that; I've never had fast user switching enabled on this laptop, and it only has one user account, so it doesn't even make sense for to be on.

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't specific to 10.8, but I only noticed it after the upgrade.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Select **User & Groups**
3. Select **Login Options** (*not* Login Items)
4. (Click the lock to make changes at the lower left corner of the window)
5. Uncheck "Show fast user switching menu as ...

Answer (score 19):

You just have to press the Command key while dragging the username out of the menu bar like you would to remove a dock item.

Comment: Thanks, this worked even when the accepted method didn't.

Answer (score 11):

This is the fast user switching menu, which can be Command + dragged off.

Further settings can be accessed through the users & groups pref pane:

[image]